# Android studio how to fix android failed linking failure

Tags: android, kotlin

so i am trying to **Rebuild Project** then this error happened help im new to android and i am just following a tutorial to learn more about android, i am trying to implement Hilt-Dagger into my application but idont know how to fix this error. here is my gradle and
Error:
[image: The Error]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androiddevs.bikemap"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha03'

    // Architectural Components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Navigation Components
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // Google Maps Location Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'

    // Dagger Core
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.38.1"

    // Dagger Android
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.2'

    //Activity KTX for ViewModels()
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1"

    //Dagger-Hilt
    implementation  'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1'
    kapt    'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'

    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

    // Easy Permissions
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'

    // Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    // MPAndroidChart
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
}
```

Windows 10

*"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Comment: Please do not fill your questions with copy-pasted content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your question, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your question being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error image it says `error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found`, so the color you used probably just **doesn't exist**. This is causing the `Android resource linking failed` error.